# Only want a Concatenation to appear when the value is not null

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

I have built a concatenation using SQL (Oracle), but I only want the concatenation to output when the value in the field is not null. I'm effectively building a website URL in the field, but in some cases the link is not yet available, but the concatenation still outputs the prefix (http://www.). If the value is null, then it should output null. At the moment I have:

```
SELECT 'http://www.'||LINK AS "URL"
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: No reason to put `URL` in quotes ... it's all-uppercase and not an Oracle reserved word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If selecting only rows from `TABLE` where `LINK IS NOT NULL` isn't an option, you can use `NVL2()` for this. It accepts three arguments - a string, the value to return if the string is not null, and the value to return if the string is null.

```
SELECT NVL2(LINK, 'http://www.'||LINK, NULL) AS "URL" FROM TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use NVL2 as the other answer suggested. Or alternatively do something like -

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LINK IS NOT NULL THEN 
         'http://www.' || LINK 
       ELSE 
         NULL 
       END
          AS "URL"
FROM TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go even further. You have Oracle so you have regular expressions at your disposal (or you do if you have 9i or greater), so you can check to see if your link already starts with `http://`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(link, '^https?:\/\/') THEN link
  WHEN link IS NOT NULL THEN 'http://www.' || link END AS url
  FROM mytable;
```

The `CASE` statement will return `NULL` if there is no `ELSE` clause, so you need not add an explicit case for `link IS NULL`. Personally, I would go so far as to make sure that `link` didn't start with `www.` as well, or if it even should.